# symfony 2 example not working

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

i have downloaded an example from github

```
https://github.com/azat/blog
```

and i am trying to implement this example in my localhost which is not working. it's show the error like bootstratp  and autoload error.
it show the following error.

```
( ! ) Warning: require_once(D:\wamp\www\blog-master\web/../app/bootstrap.php.
cache)[<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\wamp\www\
blog-master\web\app.php on line 3
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 
1   0.0009  368824  {main}( )   ..\app.php:0



( ! ) Fatal error: require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]:
Failed opening required 'D:\wamp\www\blog-master\web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache' 
(include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\wamp\www\blog-master\web\app.php on line 3
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0009  368824  {main}( )   ..\app.php:0
```

please let me know how to configure in local host

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to run `php bin/build.sh`

This script will generate bootstrap.cache (`bin/build_bootstrap.php`) and clean your project folders.

Also, beware of submodules! :) (before `build.sh` run `git submodule update --init --recursive`)

Comment: i want to run it in my wamp server in local computer

Comment: This blog example uses an older version of Symfony2. Newer versions use [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) for building and package management instead of the *nix only build.sh script.